# I need to pass textbox info from .master to .cs file

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, email

I have a form created in a .master file as part of the html for a page:

```
<form runat = "server">
     <div class="formcolumn">
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="firstname" type="text" name="firstname" value="" placeholder="First Name" /><br />
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="lastname" type="text" name="lastname" value="" placeholder="Last Name" /><br />
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="email" type="text" name="email" value="" placeholder="Email" />
    </div>
    <div class="formcolumn">
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" id="mystory" name="mystory" placeholder="My Story" />
        <asp:Button runat="server" id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="submit_Click"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

In the .cs file I have the event click handler

```
protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (MailMessage message = new MailMessage())
    {
        message.From = new MailAddress("website@mywebsites.com", "My university");
        message.To.Add(new MailAddress("me@myemail.edu"));
        message.Subject = "Why We Learn Message";
        message.Body = "First Name: " + firstname.Text;
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.Host = "127.0.0.1";
        client.Send(message);
    }
}
```

For some reason the .cs file is not able to access the firstname from the textbox and I am unsure how to pass that information to the .cs file.

Edit:
The error message says "the name 'firstname' does not exist in the current context."

Comment: firstname.Text. Should be all you have to have.

Comment: `firstname.text.toString()` is already a string `firstname.Text` and it's `.Text` not `.text`

Comment: This **firstname.text.toString();** won't even compile as "text" is not a property, while "Text" is.

Comment: When you run debug and go through when you do firstname.Text. What does it say when you scroll over it? Is the button even firing?

Comment: If I open the page like this in a browser the error is "Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'ASP.app_master_whywelearn_master' does not contain a definition for 'submit_Click' and no extension method 'submit_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.app_master_whywelearn_master' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: @JoshCoats In which `.cs` file have you got the `submit_Click` function?

Comment: @Izzy I thought your answer plus mine solved this, but it wasn't until I tried it myself that I realized. If it changes anything, this is the very first time I open a WebForms project (but not first ASP.NET) in this pc.

Comment: @cFrozenDeath I'm assuming the OP is trying to access the `firstname` Text on a childpage hence the error message

Comment: The form is in the file whywelearn.Master and the cs in is the file whywelearn.Master.cs

Answer (score 1):

Add setter and getter in master page cs file

```
public string FirstName 
        { 
         get
         { 
         return firstname.Text; 
         } 
         set 
         {
        firstname.Text = value; 
         }
        }
```

Access the FirstName  in child page with the following code sample

```
MasterPage masterPageObj = this.Master; 
string firstNameChildObj = masterPageObj.FirstName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be :

```
message.Body = "First Name: " + firstname.Text;
```

Comment: I appreciate the quick reply, but that did not work either. The error message says "the name 'firstname does not exist in the current context."

Comment: The error message says "the name 'firstname' does not exist in the current context."